# Can this be printed on same line?

Tags: linux, bash

This command will count the number of files in the sub-directories.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d |while read dir;do echo "$dir";find "$dir" -type f|wc -l;done
```

Which looks like

```
./lib64
327
./bin
118
```

Would it be possible to have it to look like

```
327 ./lib64
118 ./bin
```

instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this...  Here's something that doesn't change your code very much.  (I've put it in multiple lines for readability.)

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do
   echo `find "$dir" -type f | wc -l` "$dir"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

pipe into `tr` to remove or replace newlines. I expect you want the newline to be turned into a tab character, like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d |while read dir;do
   find "$dir" -type f|wc -l  | tr '\n' '\t';
   echo "$dir";
done
```

(Edit: I had them the wrong way around)

Answer (score 0):

`do echo -n "$dir "`

The `-n` prevents `echo` from ending the line afterwards.

Comment: That was going to be my answer @Ben, but the question is subtly different. THe goal is to print the number, followed by the directory name, on one line.   Come to think of it, I've just spotted another bug in my answer!